# Best way to create a key-value "dict" in COBOL

Tags: cobol

I'm pretty new to Cobol, and got stuck trying to create something like a python dictionary, where we pass a key and the dictionary returns its value.

Python example:

```
>>> dict
{'AC': 'Acre', 'AL': 'Alagoas', 'AP': 'Amapa'}
>>> dict['AC']
'Acre'
```

I'm trying to do this in cobol, using redefines to create two arrays (one for the keys, other for the values).
I already created the arrays, but got stucked to associate these two arrays in a key-value function, once I can only access an array with integer values.

Here goes my data division, if someone can help with code samples.

```
   DATA DIVISION.
   FILE SECTION.
   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
       01 WRK-KEYS.
           02 FILLER PIC X(2) VALUE "AC".
           02 FILLER PIC X(2) VALUE "AL".
           02 FILLER PIC X(2) VALUE "AP".

       01 WRK-TABLE-KEYS REDEFINES WRK-KEYS.
           02 WRK-KEY PIC X(2) OCCURS 3 TIMES.

       01 WRK-VALUES.
           02 FILLER PIC X(19) VALUE "Acre".
           02 FILLER PIC X(19) VALUE "Alagoas".
           02 FILLER PIC X(19) VALUE "Amapa".           

       01 WRK-TABLE-VALUES REDEFINES WRK-VALUES.
           02 WRK-VALUE PIC X(10) OCCURS 3 TIMES.
```

Comment: You're going to have problems keeping two separate arrays synchronized.  You would be better off creating one array with two values per occurs.  Your code basically reads through the array and when the key matches the search term, retrieve the value.  A linear search would be fine for a few thousand keys.  A binary search would be more efficient for a large number of keys.

Comment: Gilbert gave the right advice: create one table with a "key" and a "data" field to get something similar. To then get the data for a given key use `SEARCH` (you'll find that you need to add `INDEXED BY` and `KEY` clauses,see any COBOL language reference, for example at https://gnucobol.sourceforge.io/HTML/gnucobpg.html#SEARCH).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a table, as shown in the example below:

```
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
PROGRAM-ID. STATES.

DATA DIVISION.
   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
   01  STATES-TABLE.
       05  FILLER  PIC X(2)    VALUE  "AC".
       05  FILLER  PIC X(7)    VALUE  "Acre   ".
       05  FILLER  PIC X(2)    VALUE  "AL".
       05  FILLER  PIC X(7)    VALUE  "Alagoas".
       05  FILLER  PIC X(2)    VALUE  "AP".
       05  FILLER  PIC X(7)    VALUE  "Amapá ".
   01  RDF-STATES-TABLE REDEFINES STATES-TABLE.
       05  STATE-GROUP  OCCURS 3 TIMES.
           10  STATE-CODE      PIC X(2).
           10  STATE-NAME      PIC X(7).
PROCEDURE DIVISION.
   DISPLAY "STATES : "STATES-TABLE.
   DISPLAY 'STATE-CODE(1) : ' STATE-CODE(1).
   DISPLAY 'STATE-NAME(1) : ' STATE-NAME(1).
   DISPLAY 'STATE-CODE(2) : ' STATE-CODE(2).
   DISPLAY 'STATE-NAME(2) : ' STATE-NAME(2).
   DISPLAY 'STATE-CODE(3) : ' STATE-CODE(3).
   DISPLAY 'STATE-NAME(3) : ' STATE-NAME(3).
STOP RUN.
```

Resulting in:

```
$ ./states 
STATES : ACAcre   ALAlagoasAPAmapá 
STATE-CODE(1) : AC
STATE-NAME(1) : Acre   
STATE-CODE(2) : AL
STATE-NAME(2) : Alagoas
STATE-CODE(3) : AP
STATE-NAME(3) : Amapá
```

Remember that `á` uses two bytes in UTF-8.